# How to use ngFor in td tag?

Tags: angular

I am looping in td using ngFor but for every data it creates new cell. How to display all data in one column seperated by comma.

*Here is my html file :-*

```
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>SkillSet</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees">
            <td>Edit | Delete</td>
            <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.state}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.city}}</td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills" >
                <td> {{skill.skillName}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

*I am getting output like this :-*

```
SkillSet | Address |          |
---------|---------|----------|------
JAVA     | SQL     | Varanasi |
JAVA     | SQL     | J2EE     | BTM
JAVA     | Ranchi  |          |
```

*I want output like this :-*

```
SkillSet         | Address |
-----------------|---------|
JAVA, SQL        | Varanasi|
JAVA, SQL, J2EE  | BTM     |
JAVA             | Ranchi  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of employee.skills" >
```

This will have one `<ng-container>` (and as a consequence, one `td`) per skill. Instead, you can simply

```
<td>{{ employee.skills.join(', ') }}</td>
```

(Which would work if `skills` was an array of strings. As it isn't...)

There's a few ways to join them into an array. I'm against putting *too* much JavaScript into the markup, but you can declare a helper function in the TS:

`getSkillNames = (skills: any): string => skills.map(({ skillName}) => skillName).join(', ');`

and in the template just have

```
<td>{{ getSkillNames(employee.skills) }}</td>
```

Notice, however, that the function will get reevaluated for every row, during every change detection, which can be a performance concern. I personally would run it once on loading data, like this:

```
this.employeesWithSkillNames = this.employees.map(({skills, ...rest}) => (
    { skillNames: getSkillNames(skills), skills, ...rest })
);
```

Comment: Thanks man @mbojko , it's working but it is showing object how to get skillName?

Comment: Ah, right. I missed that it has a little more complex structure. I'll update the answer.